# ArrayList elements searching using java elastic api

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch

I am facing issues below when doing a search on elastic search:
1) When there is an ArrayList and I want or based search for that, it`s giving improper results. Below is the code snippet for the same.
code snippet of the same:

```
query1.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("game_list", Arrays.asList(listGames.getGameMode().split(","))));
```

Here I want to get any document if "game_list" matches either of the value in listData.

2)Date based matching is not working.

```
query2.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("first_game_date").lt(listGames.getFirstDate()));
```

Date is in EX:"2017-05-02T16:12:07Z" format

And then I am making the main query which has the above two subqueries.

```
BoolQueryBuilder query3 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
query3.must(query1).must(query2);
```

and this query3 I am using to do the final search.

Please let me know, what I am missing here.
Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: Please provide the final query string or complete code snippet related to building of the query. It will help to understand what's going on.

Comment: Please tell us what do you mean under "improper results": empty result set? Irrelevant results that should not be there? May you give a couple of example documents and probably the ES mapping? Thanks.

Comment: So its like i have an string which has many comma separated values and I want to apply elastic search filter in such a manner that if any of the commas separated value matches with elastic search records,, I should get results.                   For example: i have string str=" a,b,c,d" and I want to search in such a way that if elastic search field matches with any of the string value, I get result.     field: a or b or c or d . So i tried with query1.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("game_list", Arrays.asList(str.split(","))));  but not result is not getting filtered.